# How to break one array value into two string on index base in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here is my code, I am trying to break one full name into two part firstName and lastName .But its not coming in what I need .

```
Like if   fullName='Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar' . then
firstName = Sachin Ramesn
lastName = Tendulkar   if

fullName='Sachin Tendulkar' . then
firstName = Sachin  
lastname = Tendulkar

if fullName='Sachin  Ramesh Tendulkar Second' . then

firstName =Sachin  Ramesh Tendulkar
lastName= Second

   this.state={
    fullName:'Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar'
    let fullName = this.state.fullName.split(' ');
    const firstName = fullName.shift()
    const lastName = fullName.join(' ')
    --------------------------------------------
    firstName = Sachin
    lastName = Ramesh Tendulkar .
    but I have to show the result like below ..
    ------------------------------
    firstName = Sachin Ramesh
    lastName = Tendulkar
```

Please suggest . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:-

```
[fName, mName, lName] = nameString.split(" ");
if(!lName) lName = mName
else fName = fName+mName
```

So if last name is null or undefined then we assign middle name value to last name.
Else first name will be equal to first name + middle name.

Answer (score 0):

`shift` will remove the first element. I think what you want is `pop` to get the last element in order to isolate the last name. Take note that these are direct mutations

```js
var fullName = "Sachin  Ramesh Tendulkar Second".split(' ');
var lastName = fullName.pop();
var firstName = fullName.join(' ');

console.log(`firstName: `, firstName);
console.log(`lastName: `, lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const name = "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar"
const lstSpc = name.lastIndexOf(" ")
const nameParts = [name.substring(0, lstSpc), name.substring(lstSpc)] 
console.log(nameParts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
name = 'ABC XYZ GHI';
array = name.split(' ');
lastName = array.pop()
firstName = array.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fullName = "Sachin  Ramesh Tendulkar Second";

var firstName = fullName.substring(0, fullName .lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
var lastName = fullName.substring(fullName .lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);


console.log(`firstName: `, firstName);
console.log(`lastName: `, lastName);
```

Comment: fullName.substring is not a fucntion error its coming in react native

Comment: fullName is not string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `/(.*)\s([a-zA-Z]+)$/` and call the `exec` method on that pattern to get all capturing group

```js
const regEx = /(.*)\s([a-zA-Z]+)$/;

const matches = regEx.exec("Sachin  Ramesh Tendulkar Second");

const firstname = matches[1];
const lastname = matches[2];

console.log(firstname);
console.log(lastname);
```

You can see the regEx apply to all type of name combination on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/M53cmm/1

Answer (score 0):

```js
const name = 'Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar Second'
const  array = name.split(' ');
const firstName = array[0];
const midalName = array[1]
const lastName = array[2]
const newFirstNAme = firstName + ' ' + midalName
console.log(newFirstNAme)
console.log(lastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

tried and tested

```js
 const name = "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar"
        const array  = name.split(' ')
        let firstname = ''
        let lastname = ''
        if (array.length && array.length > 1) {
            array.forEach((item, i)  => {
                if ((array.length - 1) !== i) {
                    if (firstname) {
                        firstname = firstname + " " + item
                    } else {
                        firstname = item
                    }
                    
                }
            })
             lastname = array[array.length - 1]
        }
        if (array.length === 1) {
        firsname = array[0]
        }
```